# no muestra alerta al guardar js y ajax PHP

Tags: php

Hola tengo una pregunta no se en que estoy fallando, tengo un formulario basico en html e intento guardar con js y ajax con el controlador y modelo en php, el me guarda los datos del formulario en la base de datos pero no me muestra la alerta desde el js de que se guardo la verdad no se en que estoy fallando

**esto lo tengo en el js**

```html
 $.ajax({

            url:"ajax/permisos.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        success:function(respuesta){
                if(respuesta == "ok"){

                    swal.fire({
                      icon:"success",
                        title: "¡CORRECTO!",
                        text: "¡La habitación ha sido guardada exitosamente!",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                      
                    }).then(function(result){

                        if(result.value){

                          window.location = "permisos";     

                        }

                    });

                }
                console.log("respuesta", respuesta);
            }
```

lo tengo en un js con MVC  esa alerta cuando le pongo el if() no me la esta reconociendo pero si quito el if() de una funciona, necesito que funcione con el if()

**Esto es lo que tengo en el ajax**

```html
class AjaxHabitaciones{

    public $GuardarNombre;
    public $GuardarCedula;

    public function ajaxNuevaHabitacion(){
    
        $datos = array( "GuardarNombre" => $this->GuardarNombre,
                        "GuardarCedula" => $this->GuardarCedula);

        $respuesta = ControladorPruebas::ctrNuevaPrueba($datos);

        echo $respuesta;

    }

}
if(isset($_POST["GuardarNombre"])){

    $habitacion = new AjaxHabitaciones();
    $habitacion -> GuardarNombre = $_POST["GuardarNombre"];
    $habitacion -> GuardarCedula = $_POST["GuardarCedula"];
    $habitacion -> ajaxNuevaHabitacion();
 
}
```

Este codigo tambien funciona me trae la repsuesta y el ok pero no funciona con la alerta

ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO EN EL CONTROLADOR

```html
static public function ctrNuevaPrueba($datos){

    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $datos["GuardarNombre"]) && 
       preg_match('/^[_\\a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $datos["GuardarCedula"])){

       
        $tabla = "prueba";

        $datos = array("nombre" => $datos["GuardarNombre"],
                        "cedula" => $datos["GuardarCedula"]);

        $respuesta = ModeloPruebas::mdlPruebas($tabla, $datos);

        return $respuesta; 

    }else{

        echo '<script>

                swal.fire({

                    icon:"error",
                    title: "¡CORREGIR!",
                    text: "¡No se permiten caracteres especiales en ninguno de los campos!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
```

**y en mi modelo**

```html
static public function mdlPruebas($tabla, $datos){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre,cedula) VALUES (:nombre,:cedula)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":cedula", $datos["cedula"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


        if($stmt->execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{

            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r(Conexion::conectar()->errorInfo());
        
        }
```

Comment: acabo de probar peor me sale este error... Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::close() in thrown in <b>C:\xampp8.1.7\htdocs\pruebas\modelos\pruebas.modelo.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />

Comment: cuando le pongo el echo

Comment: Perdon, no hagas esos cambios, no me di cuenta de que vas retornando el ok entre distintas funciones, hasta llegar al `echo $respuesta`.... déjalo todo como estaba al principio antes de que metiera la pata

Comment: haaa ok ajja dale